# Haskell Incorrect IO output

Tags: design-patterns, haskell, io, return

This is what I have, I want an output like this

```
*Main> sumThree
Please enter three integers:
1
2
3
Their sum is: 6
(1,2,3)
```

I however keep getting , without the summ

```
*Main> sumThree
Please enter three integers:
1
2
3
Their sum is:
(1,2,3)
```

---

```
**summ :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> IO Integer
summ x1 x2 x3 = return(x1+x2+x3)
sumThree :: IO (Integer, Integer, Integer)
sumThree = do putStr "Please enter tree integers:"
              x1 <- getInteger
              x2 <- getInteger
              x3 <- getInteger
              putStr "Their Sum is: "
              summ x1 x2 x3
              return(x1,x2,x3)**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually print the result of `summ`.

Don't `return` in your `summ` function, so that the function's result type is `Integer` as opposed to `IO Integer`. Then, do

```
putStr (show (summ x1 x2 x3))
```

instead of just `summ x1 x2 x3`.

Also, you do know about the `sum` built-in (Prelude) function right? It takes an array of `Num`'s, so you can just do `putStr (show (sum [x1, x2, x3]))`.

Comment: are you allowed to have only 1 return in the function?

Comment: No you can have more than one return. In Haskell, `return` is just a function that has the signature `a -> M a` for some monad M. In this case, you're in the `IO` monad, so `return` has the type `a -> IO a`. You should read up on Monads and how they work in Haskell. In short, `return` in Haskell (and in monad terminology) is just a function to convert a plain value into a monadic value, and is entirely unrelated to the concept of the "return statement" in imperative languages.

Answer (score 1):

I might be reading a bit too much into your code here, so please correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you are confused about how Haskell programs work, and in particular about what `return` means.

`return` in Haskell is not the return statement you might be familiar with from many imperative programming languages. `return` in Haskell is a *function*. Like any other function you apply it to an argument to compute a value. It has **no effect** on flow control, and in particular it does not cause its argument to be "returned" as the value computed by the function you're in.

For the `IO` monad, `return` is a function of this type: `return :: a -> IO a`, which means it takes a value in any type and gives you a value in "the `IO` version of that type". In the particular case of `return`, it gives you a do-nothing IO-computation that will produce that value.

This:

```
summ :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> IO Integer
summ x1 x2 x3 = return(x1+x2+x3)
```

is a very odd function to a Haskell programmer. There's no need to do IO to compute the sum of 3 integers, so why is the result type `IO Integer`? It *looks* to me like you've tried to write this:

```
summ :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
summ x1 x2 x3 = return(x1+x2+x3)
```

which would have given you a type error about `Integer` not being a monadic type. You can fix that by changing the type, but the type was a correct expression of summing 3 integers, so changing that to something else is rather odd. Since `return` isn't at all necessary to computer the result of a function, you can just do this instead:

```
summ :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
summ x1 x2 x3 = x1+x2+x3
```

Likewise, your `sumThree` function is very odd. When you do this in the Haskell interpreter:

```
*Main> sumThree
Please enter three integers:
1
2
3
Their sum is:
(1,2,3)
```

The interpreter is evaluating the `sumThree` IO action, which asks you to enter 3 integers and prints "Their sum is:", and produces the value `(1, 2, 3)`. The `sumThree` action itself does not print anything after `"Their sum is:"`, it's the interpreter that is printing that for you, and it's printing the value produced by executing `sumThree`.

It's the last thing in the do block that determines the value produced by `sumThree`; in this case that's `return(x1,x2,x3)`. So you can see that there's no way that could possibly be the sum of the 3 numbers, since you're quite explicitly taking the tuple `(x1, x2, x3)`, wrapping it up into an `IO` action with `return`, and then that's the result.

Your second last line:

```
summ x1 x2 x3
```

is an `IO` action (thanks to the type `Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> IO Integer` for `summ`). So it's allowed to sit there, and it is "executed" to produce its value, but you don't do anything with it!

So two things:

1. `summ` doesn't need `return` at all
2. `sumThree` should actually print what you want it to print

Putting that together you could get something like this:

```
summ :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
summ x1 x2 x3 = x1 + x2 + x3

sumThree :: IO ()
sumThree = do putStr "Please enter tree integers:"
              x1 <- getInteger
              x2 <- getInteger
              x3 <- getInteger
              putStr "Their Sum is: "
              putStr (show (summ x1 x2 x3))
```

That's if you don't want `sumThree` to produce the sum as well as printing it. If `sumThree` *should* produce the value as well as printing it, you'd want something more like this:

```
summ :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
summ x1 x2 x3 = x1 + x2 + x3

sumThree :: IO Integer
sumThree = do putStr "Please enter tree integers:"
              x1 <- getInteger
              x2 <- getInteger
              x3 <- getInteger
              putStr "Their Sum is: "
              putStr (show (summ x1 x2 x3))
              return (summ x1 x2 x3)
```